# Add a footer on title page without \maketitle

Tags: titles

I'm currently work on my title page and I'd like to add a footer. I tried to use fancy without success. I think it's because I don't use the command `\maketitle`.

My title page below:

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtUpperLeftCorner{1.5cm}{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{herox-logo.png}}
  \AtUpperRightCorner{1.5cm}{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{ntl-logo.png}}
}

\vspace*{2cm}
\noindent
\hrulefill
\vspace*{0.3cm}
\begin{center}
{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont \Huge{\@title}\\%
\ifdefined\subtitle
\vspace{1cm}
\LARGE{\subtitle}%
\fi}
\end{center}
\hrulefill
\begin{flushright}
\emph{\@author}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent

\end{titlepage}
\makeatother   
\ClearShipoutPicture
```

The comands `\AtUpperLeftCorner` and `\AtUpperRightCorner` are defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{#1\vss}}
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\put(\LenToUnit{#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{#3}}%
}
\newcommand\AtTopCenterPage[2]{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#1})
{\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtQuasiTopCenterPage[2]{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{.6\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#1})
{\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2})
{\blap{\llap{#3}}}%
}
```

This part of the code is not mine, so I don't know exactly how it works; but it's only for pictures and header. **I want to put a text in the footer.**

How could I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you take a look at the `titling` package? It makes it easy to customise the command `\maketitle`.

Comment: Thanks! First time I need to post!
Hum, I tried ``titling`` but I didn't work well. Maybe I missed smewhre.

Comment: Don't use \subtitle and stuff like that if you don't want to use \maketitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking a complete MWE, I was unable to test the following:

```
\newcommand\AtBottomCenterPage[2]{% #1 = distance from bottom, #2 = text
 \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#1})
{\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtBottomRightCorner[3]{% #1 = distance from right edge, #2 = distance from bottom, #3=text
\put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-#1},\LenToUnit{#2})
{\blap{\llap{#3}}}%
}
```

The use of `\put` indicates that `\AddToShipoutPicture` uses a `picture` environment which overlays the entire page.  Picture is part of core LaTeX but is rarely used anymore.

It would also help to know exactly where the footer area is.

```
\the\dimexpr \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-\footskip\relax
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand exactlyhow it works, but it works! :)
If I would like to put in the right corner, should I do as in the header (subtract an arbitrary lenght)?

Comment: Just added \AtBottomRightCorner